# Where is _SECURE_SCL normally found?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I'm convinced I have some `std::vector` bounds problems in a project built using Visual Studio 2005. According to the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I can control bounds checking using `_SECURE_SCL`. It assures me that it is enabled by default - courtesy of a `#define _SECURE_SCL 1` somewhere. I certainly can't find it, and if I slip that definition into `stdafx.h`, it doesn't conflict with anything. Am I missing something? What is the "normal" way to use `_SECURE_SCL`?

Comment: According to the linked doc, _SECURE_SCL is only relevant for iterators, not all std::vector stuff.

Comment: But 99% of the way I access my vectors are via .front(), .back() or operator[], all of which are explicitly listed in that documentation... so it screams relevance to me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it's defined in the header file `yvals.h`.

- If both `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` and `HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` are undefined, `HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` defaults to `1` in a debug build.
- If `_SECURE_SCL` is undefined, and `HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is defined as `1`, `_SECURE_SCL` defaults to `1`

Different rules come into play if `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is defined. See the header file for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't see how (or if) yyvals.h is included, but at least the code in it makes it much clearer what happens than the MS documentation.

Comment: OK - _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL seems to only apply from Visual Studio 2012 onwards. VS2005 only knows about _SECURE_SCL and HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING. yyvals.h is included through <vector> including <stdexcept> then <exception> then <xstddef> which finally includes yyvals.h. Good enough for a tick from me - thanks!